# Change the d.children value for different svg - d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

So, I have three tree's organization on my webpage, and when I click on a blue rectangle, a subpart appears or disappears. The problem is that, when I click, a subpart appears or disappears, but to only one tree of all of the trees, but I intended to do it for all different trees (all of the trees on the page are the same).

I tried to do this but this work only for one tree:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BvirRFMFrR96PtioXDzQ

So this is the part on the code that we need to change:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(source, svg_var, svg_id, all_sources);
    });
```

Comment: How is this different from your other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309905/change-the-d-children-value-for-differant-svg-d3-js? Please edit your other question instead of creating a new question. Please also consider reading through some d3 tutorials so that you understand more about how to perform the different operations that you have requested in your recent questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the value of d.children for different SVG’s - D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308032/change-the-value-of-d-children-for-different-svg-s-d3-js)

Comment: I tought that i delete the other questions, my bad. And i already looked in internet and did a lot a things but it doesn't work, so this is why im here :) @ialarmedalien

Comment: Anyone can help me ? :(